# Send a csv file and its md5 hash via HTTP Post (Java)

Tags: java, http, post

I am trying to send a csv file and its md5 via HTTP Post in Java. I had been trying it out with HttpClient with its examples, but was not able to find a suitable example that sends BOTH csv file and its md5 hash via HTTP Post.

I am able to calculate the md5 but am stuck at the sending of csv file.

Thanks and hope to hear from all.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, howto upload a file using HttpClient:
http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload

you can send MD5 Hash using a custom header:

```
httppost.setHeader("My-Checksum",calculateMD5(/* content of CSV */));
```

and you can read it with HttpServletRequest's getHeader() like this:

```
String md5Sum = request.getHeader("My-Checksum");
```

Comment: Given its age, the TSS post probably uses HttpClient 3 (if not earlier). Which is fine, but be aware that the instructions do not apply to HttpClient 4.

Comment: Hi kdgregory, thanks for the heads up as well! I have converted it to HttpClient4. Will be testing it sending a file and associated md5 to another server later today!